# What is a template with set headings called?

Tags: word-usage, word-choice, word-request

At my university, we have a template for describing courses, containing a number of set headings under each of which information pertaining to the individual course is added – headings such as "Number of credits" "Content", "Tuition", "Examination" etc. Now I'm wondering what would be the best word for this kind of template – does *heading template* work, or should I use something else? I have looked up *heading template* in dictionaries without success (Cambridge, Merriam-Webster and Longman), and when I google "heading template", the hits I get seem to refer mostly to computer programmes... Any help here would be greatly appreciated :)

Comment: I'm not sure it needs to be anything more specific than "template." The whole point of a template is that some set elements are provided, and other content can be customized. If we need a modifying word, maybe this is a "course template," since the application is specific to each course?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Heading template" is a compound noun- two words put together to make something more specific than either of the individual words. Compound nouns don't normally appear in dictionaries, because you can generally deduce the meaning of a compound noun from the individual words- a milk bottle is a bottle intended to contain milk.

Regarding "heading template": the complete set of information- headings and data- is called a table.  My guess is that you would need to supply a template for both the headings and the (initially empty) columns underneath them, so "table template" might be the best way to describe it. If you do literally just want the headings, "heading template" is OK.